# Errors when compiling an audio driver with ReactOS Build Environment

Tags: windows, audio, driver, react-os

When I compile the driver's source code (which can be downloaded at https://u.teknik.io/Rq3cw.zip) using ReactOS Build Environment (available at https://downloads.sourceforge.net/reactos/RosBE-2.2.0.exe) and Git for Windows (available at https://git-scm.com/download/win), I get the errors shown in https://paste.ee/p/husrG. I am able to replicate those errors by doing the following:

1. Open a Command Prompt Window.
2. Type cd c:\ and press Enter.
3. Type git clone https://github.com/reactos/reactos.git and press Enter.
4. Close the Command Prompt Window.
5. Install ReactOS Build Environment and set the path of the source to C:\reactos while installing it.
6. Extract the archive containing the driver's source to C:\reactos\drivers\wdm\audio\drivers.
7. Open ReactOS Build Environment.
8. Type configure and press Enter.
9. Type cd output-mingw-i386 and press Enter.
10. Type ninja ac97smpl and press Enter.

Comment: reactOS team recently jumped from GCC 4.7.2 to GCC 8.4.0 . It looks like new version of GCC does not like source code of your driver. I suggest you to either try previous version of RosBE or fix source code of driver. ReactOS project has multiple forums where developers hang out. You can ask such support questions there

Comment: I don't think that's the case. The developers aren't going to help me.

Comment: Will anyone try to fix them soon?